# Breeze query with multiple conditions

Tags: breeze

How to write a breeze query with 2 'where' conditions?

the following doesn't work:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Boilers")
.where('boilerMakeID', '==', $rootScope.boilerMakeID)
.and('actueel', '==', true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Predicates...

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/Predicate.html

```
var pred1 = Predicate.create("boilerMakeID", "==", $rootScope.boilerMakeID);
var pred2 = Predicate.create("actueel", "==", true);
var newPred = pred1.and(pred2);

var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Boilers").where(newPred)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use predicates...

```
var p1=new breeze.Predicate("boilerMakeId","==",$rootScope.boilerMakeID);
var p2=new breeze.Predicate("actueel","==",true);
var predicate=p1.and(p2);


var query=breeze.EntityQuery.from("Boilers").where(predicate);
```